# Software (an old PC game) won't boot using a virtual drive, but does boot using a real drive. How come?

Tags: iso-image, compact-disc, disk-image, virtual-drive

I have a couple of old video games—*The Hobbit* (2003), published by Vivendi, and *Zapper: One Wicked Cricket* (2002), published by Infogrames—which won't boot when mounted using a virtual drive, but they do boot using the game CD in a real drive (not all old games have this problem). I thought virtual drives were indistinguishable from virtual ones. How can I circumvent this? I have already tried changing the drive letters, but to no avail.

I use Windows XP SP3 32-bit. I used CloneCD to create the images and VirtualCloneDrive to mount them. I have also tried WinCDEmu.

Comment: They were designed to prevent you doing that... otherwise all your friends would have a copy too. Circumventing that would be off-topic.

Comment: For what it's worth, I say YAY for those publishers.  If it was easy to clone a protected CD, you'd be able to share it with people who did not pay for it.  Perhaps you don't care, but when people steal software, it affects those of us who create such software.  Not saying you're stealing it, since you can run it on the CD drive, but there's a reason it only runs on a CD drive.

Comment: well, except for SecureROM or Sony. burning out other peoples disk drives prematurely or installing rootkits on their boxes are unacceptable means to protect your imaginary property.

Comment: It's abandonware. These are old games which aren't available digitally (and barely available physically apart from some second hand sites). Of course I understand the reasons publishers have as a business, and I totally respect those, but as these games aren't available anymore, and I would like to preserve them only for the sake of nostalgia (and without sharing them), I was just wondering whether this was possible with today's technology. I mean no harm, I just would like to be able to play these old games in the future.

Comment: @EmielBoss They are still copyrighted.  They still have DRM unless they have been republished at say GoG or Steam and received patches to remove the drm

Comment: “Digital rights management (DRM) is a set of access control technologies for restricting the use of proprietary hardware and copyrighted works.“ is the definition that Wikipedia provides to DRM.  DRM is what would prevent the disk to be duplicated.  I disagree with the notion, that copying the game disk, doesn’t have anything to do with copyrights.  Exceptions existing to law, that make breaking the DRM illegal in a single country, doesn’t chnage the fact the material is copyrighted (which was my only point).  The publisher would still be required to remove the DRM (has happened many times)

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturers put protection on discs, usually coded in some of the main application files, to prevent illegal copying and distribution. These days newer games can be downloaded when you buy them so that problem is fading away. But as a gamer myself, I know how physical discs get scratched and damaged from everyday use.

In most countries, *it is legal to make usable backups of these discs for your own use (to prevent damage to the original ones) IF YOU OWN THE ORIGINAL disc(s).*

For older games spesificly (and maybe some newer ones) you can visit [Game Burn World](http://www.gameburnworld.com/) to see if they have the specific "protection removed" files you need to make your back up copy.

**Note: It is a crime to make such copies if you do not own the original software or distribute such copies to other parties.**

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I own all the games personally, so that's no problem. I assume Game Burn Word is more or less the same as Game Copy World? Or is one of them strictly better?

Comment: @EmielBoss They are pretty much the same thing.